# Как передать xml файл на веб страницу

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net, asp.net-webforms

Есть aspx страница, мне нужно передать xml файл и получить ответ. Что-то типо такого:

```
xmlResponse = LoadXML(patch, xmlRequest)
```

Как можно такое реализовать?

Comment: Что подразумевается под "передать файл"? Точно ли вы хотите залить файл на сервер? Вероятно, вы хотите сделать HTTP-запрос (еще более вероятно, что POST) и передать XML-данные? Пока что вопрос звучит неясно.

Comment: Заливать я не хочу, скорее вы правы, мне необходимо сделать запрос и передать ему XML, на той странице лежит обработчик, который вернет ответ на основании полученной XML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам необходимо сделать POST-запрос, то самый простой способ - это использовать класс `WebClient`.

```
string xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"/><body></body>";

WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/xml"; // если необходимо
string response = client.UploadString("http://localhost/yoururl", xml);
```

Метод `UploadString` выполнит HTTP-запрос с методом POST и вернёт строку, содержащую ответ сервера. В случае неуспеха `WebClient` выбросит `WebException`.

Comment: "Удаленный сервер возвратил ошибку: (401) Несанкционированный." Что то с правами?

Comment: client.UseDefaultCredentials = true; исправляет, только не могу понять для чего это нужно

Comment: @e1s вероятно, сервис использует Windows-аутентификацию. Сделайте сервис с анонимной аутентификацией и такой проблемы возникнуть не должно.

Comment: Я не могу менять ее, только использовать